# MAX232 chip fails to initialize properly with arduino

Tags: serial, power, arduino-due, max232

I have connected a MAX232 chip for RS232 communication with my Arduino.
The chip input is connected to Arduino Tx and it is getting power from external 3.3 volt dc power source.

My Arduino is also getting power from 12 volt DC external power source.

While I connect and start the device, the PC is not getting any data until I reboot the MAX232.

How do I make a robust setup so that after I turn the powers on, it starts transmitting. Even if connection to my PC has been lost.

Comment: MAX232 is not a microprocessor, and does not require initialization. It's really just an inverting level converter. Can you show a schematic of how you have it connected? Also, the typical MAX232 is a 5V part, so 3.3V powering it won't be reliable.

Comment: Agreed - for 3.3V operation you need to use the MAX**3**232.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Datasheet for MAX232](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max232.pdf)

> Section 7.3 Recommended Operating Conditions VCC Supply voltage
>
> MIN=4.5, NOM=5, MAX=5.5 (V)

The MAX232 has a minimum supply voltage of 4.5V, typically expecting 5V.

There are other alternatives, such as the [MAX3232](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max3232.pdf), which supports either 3.3V or 5V supply voltage.

Comment: Thanks,  I also found that error in datasheet about 5 volt power. But is there any startup sequence?

Comment: Say i have to turn 12 volt power first, then 3.3 and then connect it to the pc. Is there any logic behind proper startup sequence? 
I am using different power sources.

Comment: The MAX232 chip has no 12V supply. There is no startup sequence.

Comment: I have tried whatever I found here, but still I am unable to send data from Arduino to pc via MAX232. I have only connected the TX line, ground from Arduino to MAX232 chip, thats what i need actually (Arduino here is not supposed to get any data).

Comment: All common grounds are okay. Power lines are okay. Connections are too properly done.

Comment: I figured out the problem. There was no delay in my code. A 100 ms delay solved the issue. There is some specific switching frequency for the MAX232.

Comment: The 5v vcc also needs a resistor of some value to prevent the chip from overheating.